# kogrid javascript library runtime exception

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js, kogrid

I have just installed kogrid through NUget I am using simple grid example provided [here](http://ericmbarnard.github.com/KoGrid/#/examples)

but when i run my mvc application it just throws following exception in kogrid.js file

Microsoft Jscript runtime Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'peek'

Comment: What is your KO version? The `peek` function was added in **Knockout 2.2.0.**

Comment: thanks it resolved the issue. It mean Nuget package is not correct :( knockout 2.2.1 should be installed separately.